# Safari dev tools problem when debugging remotely

Tags: css, macos, debugging, ipad, safari

Probably some of you faced similar problem of Safari dev tools.

When I debug CSS properties of elements on Safari dev tools, it's fine - I can enable/disable different properties and they're get commented/uncommented (see attached picture), but when I start debugging iPad pages remotely - it's different...

When I disable some CSS property, it disappears instead of getting commented. I have no other possibility to enable it. I must add it manually... It's annoying...

Do you know the solution?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. I use iPad 4 which has no more iOS updates available (last one is ver.11).

However I could get rid of the problem by going to dev tools settings, selecting experimental tab and checking the "Legacy style editor" checkbox[image]

I hope it will help someone of you.